# If "tag" is "event" - how to do condition with php

Tags: theming

I need to do a condition on a tpl.php

Basically I have a content type with taxonomy "tags" - some are News, some are Events.

On the page.tlp I want to do the following condition:

```
if ($content['field_tags']=='Events'):

    <p>test</p>

endif;
```

But this doesn't work.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you will find it in `node.tpl.php`

```
$content['field_tags']['#items'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name
```

Be sure to test it for empty() or run it through isset() before you use it.
[image]

Comment: that worked! Thank you! one question: how can I have it in a list like you have? It seems so simple looking at that

Comment: I have set a breakpoint on the code in my IDE and have XDebug PHP extension installed. You can also install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use dpm(). Consult [Drupal debugging: Xdebug and Devel](http://www.codesidekick.com/blog/drupal-debugging-xdebug-and-devel)

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this

```
if ($content["field_tags"] == 'Events') 
echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor met</p>';
```

Comment: But when I print $content['field_tags'] it appears "Events" on the page. Is the condition that is not working